# Alternative to Session in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've read that Session is disabled within SharePoint by default (I've heard due to performance). I have a situation that seems like it would fit in session, but I don't want to enable session if I can help it, I'd prefer to look at the alternatives but I'm struggling to find out what they are. I can find lots of questions discussing how to enable it, but haven't found much on alternatives.

My situation is I wish to have a combobox that appears on most of the pages within my solution. This combobox is going to modify the databinding slightly (by modifying a variable) on almost every page, and I want it to remain consistent across the site for a user. Almost like a "What Language do you want the page in?" or a "What Year would you like the data for?". Obviously this information should be persisted on a per-user basis and it doesn't matter if it is lost when the user logs out particularly.

What alternatives do I have instead of using session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Session is disabled for performance as much as it is disabled due to the potential for multiple web front ends. If your web application is on a farm of only one front end, you might want to try enabling Session. You might actually see a performance gain because suddenly the state that SharePoint would otherwise store in the content database is no longer a round trip away, but rather is now available on the web server. At least, that has been my experience. I have noticed a slight performance boost from enabling Session on a single front end farm that receives moderate volume.

That said, if Session is definitely out, I would probably choose cookies next, as @agrothe suggests. If cookies are out and if it is a single front end farm, I might try the site Property Bag. But as noted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/7d4ed3c2-343b-4d0d-9b65-878ca786bbb8), the Property Bag is not really meant as a Session substitute, so you'll need to make sure that you use unique keys and remove the key value pairs when you are done with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rich. I actually discovered and decided to use the SPPropertyBag on the SPWeb object. As I read more about it, what I'm doing isn't actually 'Session' as such. It's a single value per user and saving it across sessions is no bad thing, so I don't need to worry about cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using cookies to store the information client side? Something along [these lines](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/cookie-creation-session-management)

This might work, but could also introduce some more complexity depending on the where the dropdowns are rendered in the page life cycle.

This could also be a security concern, but for simple filter data, that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought about using cookies. Some of the places where we deploy may be locked down so cookies might not be a good option... but good suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, cookies are always dicey that way. Your own database could be another option, but then you have to install it everywhere you deploy. Also dicey.